# How to test iPad Pro on the iOS simulator

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

It's been hinted at that the iOS simulator can be resized to show the full size keyboard in the iPad Pro (http://www.fastcompany.com/3047871/tech-forecast/the-ipad-pro-doesnt-need-a-physical-keyboard), which presumably would allow for the testing of an app in that screen size, but I haven't found a way to do it. The GM seed of Xcode 7 even has the iPhone 6S and 6S Plus, but no iPad Pro in sight. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I think it will be available with iOS 9.1.

Comment: There's an iPad Pro simulator in Xcode 7.1 Beta, but right now if you run on it, it runs as a Retina iPad scaled down somehow.

Comment: Figured it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run on the iPad Pro simulator in Xcode 7.1 Beta and use a storyboard (not an assets file) as your launch screen, it works great.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Jefferson. That does the trick. The keyboard looks like the regular iPad one, so I think for now it's just scaling my app to the bigger resolution...

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread:
[iPad Pro launch image and App icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875678/ipad-pro-launch-image-and-app-icon/33752847#33752847)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged.