# iPad Pro launch image and App icon

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios9, ios9.1, xcode7.1

iPad Pro requires 167x167 App icon and 2732 x 2048 (landscape) launch image. But where should I put them? Xcode 7.1 Asset Catalogs don't provide any place to add iPad Pro specific icons or images.

My launch image is size specific, so using storyboard for this isn't a good option.

Answer (score 9):

Apple commented on this issue: "Latest beta (7.2b3) added 83.5@2x app icon slot to asset catalogs, and Developer relations reported in a radar comment that they no longer support launch images and will not be adding the iPad pro launch image size to asset catalogs."

Taken from [here](https://openradar.appspot.com/22915712).

Comment: When does Xcode 7.2 or 7.3 with iPad PRO app icon for asset catalog launch ?App store is only giving me Xcode 7.1.1 update.

Comment: What do we call the icon for the iPad Pro? I understand it's 167 x 167 size, but what is the file to be called?

Comment: I can confirm that Xcode 7.2 does indeed add a spot for the the ipad pro app icon. I was afraid of that regarding the launch images, but at least its good to know not to hold my breath, thanks. Honestly, #$%@* Apple for how little they care about backwards compatibility :/

Comment: Do you know what the naming convention of the new icon has to be @MohamedHafez?

Comment: @amitsbajaj if you are using the asset catalog, then you can call it anything you like and just drag it into the available slot. If you aren't using the asset catalog, sorry I don't know what the naming convention would be, or even if there is one. I'd suggest updating to the asset catalog if that's the case, it only took 10 min back when i did it a couple years ago

Comment: Thanks @MohamedHafez - I'm using the Asset Catalog but I didn't realise I could cal lit anything - I thought it still had to have specific names but thanks man! Will give that a go!

Answer (score 7):

Use Launch Screen storyboard.

You can also disable Launch Screen File and Launch Images Source from project General settings and use the old way - define all Launch Images in Info.plist.

Info.plist:

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>DefaultPro-Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{1366, 1024}</string>
    </dict>
...
</array>
```

More info about UILaunchImages in Info.plist in this post:
[How do I create launch images for iPhone 6 / 6 Plus Landscape Only Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926661/how-do-i-create-launch-images-for-iphone-6-6-plus-landscape-only-apps)

Comment: I think it should be `{1024, 1366}` regardless of the orientation. That works for me in the iPad Pro simulator, but `{1366, 1024}` doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [Launch Screen Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW4) for iPad Pro instead of Launch Images.
First, from iPad Pro, iOS don't support Launch Images, so you can not find the right sizes for iPad Pro's launch images in Xcode 7.1.
Second, if you don't use Launch Screen File, you app running on iPad Pro will be scaled, which is so called 'Display Zoom'.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll need to use the Launch Screen storyboard or xib file to support launch screens specific for iPad Pro.

Per Apple, you should be able to use both the launch image assets to support pre-iOS8, and the Launch Screen file for iOS8+. From the [Apple App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html) :

"For iOS 7 deployment targets, you can supply both a launch screen file and launch images. In iOS 8, the launch screen file is used, and in iOS 7, the launch images are used."

also [these docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) state:

"If you also need to support earlier versions of iOS, you can continue to supply static launch images in addition to a launch file."

However, in my case even though I have a LaunchScreen.storyboard file, it isn't getting used when I have launch images in an asset catalog. i.e.: I always see the asset catalog launch images instead of the launch screen. I verified the Launch Screen file is set in the info.plist and that it has the "Use as Launch Screen" flag set. I'm also using size classes and auto layout.

Comment: I figured out why my Launch Screen file wasn't getting used. I had to set its view controller flag "Is Initial View Controller".

Comment: Yes, but since my launch image is size specific, Launch Screen storyboard isn't a good option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the "wells" where to put the icons in asset catalogue, perhaps you changed your App settings from iPhone to iPad at a later point and then the iPad "wells" are not visible. You can turn them on by doing this:

**The set will only contain image wells for icons that are relevant depending upon your project's configuration at the time the asset catalog was created. If an image well is missing, *expand the settings inspector and check the appropriate boxes* under the App Icon pane depending upon your project's deployment target and supported devices.**